# Java: native methods of the classes with same names in different packages

Tags: java

I am learning java native methods using Java Complete Reference 9'th edition (Shildt). As I see the native method which must be implemented in C (our case) is like this: Java_ClassName_methodName. The question is how to distinguish methods with the same names in classes with the same names but which are in different packages. Is it possible?

Comment: Use fully qualified names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your book is incorrect if that's what it says. The JNI method name must include the package name as well as the class and method names. However the question is fully resolved for you by using the `javah` tool to generate the .h file.